# PUT and DELETE requets are not working in Web API 2 even I have enabled cors

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have an angularjs web app. I have integrated this web api there. Get and Post
requests are working but when I am trying to Put and Delete requests It is giving an error :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
/#/Delete:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://abc.example.net/api/employees/3. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.net' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

I have written this below code in WebApiConfig.

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
                 var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("http://example.net", "*", "*");
                 config.EnableCors(cors);

        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
                    config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
                    config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a DynamicPoliceProviderFactory class to add all subdomains to the CORS policy or change first parameter of EnableCorsAttribute to * to allow all Origins.